# Jquery DataTable - check ajax return data before table load

Tags: jquery, datatable

Is there a way for jquery DataTable to do some task after the ajax call and then this task will determine to continue with table load with new data or just do some other jquery process?

I tried using dataSrc inside ajax and then reading specific json field data but I can't have certain value then display a pop up while the table data stay as it is before some one click any page or submit button.

Is that possible?

Comment: What you are looking for is dataFilter

Comment: @Bindrid, never heard about `dataFilter`, can you please point to the documentation for that?

Answer (score 0):

This show where and how to use the dataFilter.

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                 "serverSide": true,
                "ajax":{

            url: "wsService.asmx/GetDTDataSerializedList",
            type: "Post",
            dataFilter: function (res) {

                // do what you need to the data before it loads to the table

               return res;
            },
            error:function(x, y){
                        console.log(x);

                    }
                },
                "columns": [
                { "data": "first_name" },
                { "data": "last_name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }
                ]
            });
        });
```